# Assembly language offsetting multiple ways to store words?

Tags: assembly, mips, offset

I am using MIPS with the mars editor and I was wondering if something like

```
sw $s0,8($v0)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
sw $s0,$v0(8)
```

My instinct tells me this is not the case because it takes the address of whatevers in the brackets and adds the value of whatever is outside it. However in the solution posted by codeknight in the link beliw he loops through a string using:

```
lb $t1,mystring($t0)
```

which almost feels like indexing an array and doesn't make sense to me with the "add immediate to address of ()" logic. Can someone explain this?

http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=786dd40408172108b65a5a36b09c88c0&topic=1062.0

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, the syntax is a little confusing because it hints that the two parts are not on the same level, when in fact they are. Because of this, some assemblers allow you to put the brackets around the immediate part, but that's rather the exception.

`imm(reg)` just means memory address `imm+reg`, as such `mystring($t0)` means memory address `mystring+$t0` so it's indeed indexing. Whether the immediate part is the base or the other way around, makes no difference. Both of these load the 5th (offset 4) byte of `mystring`:

```
li $t0, 4
lb $t0, mystring($t0)
```

or

```
la $t0, mystring
lb $t0, 4($t0)
```